# UICollectionViewLayout with Horizontal Scroll and Pagination enabled

Tags: ios, gridview, pagination, horizontal-scrolling, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]
[image]

I need to prepare a layout like IOS spring board i.e Grids with horizontal scrolling, pagination enabled and most importantly Cells should be arranged row wise not column wise(in 2nd image).I tried to do this using UICollectionViewFlowLayout but it arranges the cells column wise(like  first image).

Later i come to know, this can be achieved with UICollectionViewLayout but i'm bit confused with the Apple Documentation on few points:
**1.**How to get horizontal Scrolling using UICollectionViewLayout.
**2.**Can we enable pagination.
**3.**Is it using Rows & columns concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. UiCollectionviewLayout doesn't have any default scrolling
   property.If we set the ContentSize more in Width it will
   automatically enable Horizontal Scrolling ,same for vertical
   scrolling and if fill in both width and height it will enable both
   horizontal and vertical scrolling.
2. Pagination can enabled by using :

   ```
   collectionviewlayout.collectionview.pagingEnabled = YES;
   ```
3. It don't have any Rows & Column concept,it all depends upon the user
   customisation.
   [Apple Documentation For UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/collectionViewContentSize)

   [Damir.me](http://damir.me/posts/implementing-uicollectionview-layout)